# synch mysql command line monitor on mac(10.8)

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I have downloaded mysql workbench on my mac to have a gui for my mysql installation.
I have set the connection to '127.0.0.1(localhost):3306' succesfully
I have created a new database with some table, all works well.
 
Now when i start mysql command line monitor from a terminal session:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

And ask for a 'show databases', i cant see the newly created database.
So i did:
 1)a `mysqladmin reload`:nothing, 
2)reboot the system: nothing.
How can i synch mysql command line monitor to see the new db?
When i check the 'server status'option on workbench all seems fine, i mean i see its pointing to localhost:3306 and all directories listed there are perfectly matching my local installation, i checked this because at one point i thought that i had 2 mysql installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u<the same user as in workbench> -p`

then authenticate with the same password you use in workbench.

Comment: great Sasha, merci